# Grafana Alert Value String Templating

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, go-templates, grafana-templating, grafana-api

I'm creating a Grafana alert with the Elastic datasource. The condition operator is grouping all meaningful labels from my alert.

```
[ var='A0' metric='' labels={header_host=hostname1.com value=1496 ], [ var='A1' metric='' labels={header_host=hostname2.com} value=1178 ], [ var='A2' metric='' labels={header_host=hostname3.com} value=764 ], [ var='A3' metric='' labels={header_host=hostname4.com} value=505 ]
```

Please not that these results are dynamic. Any hostname could become a different hostname.

Since I can't/don't know how to make a unique alert for each result, I'm trying to range over the value string listed there.

```
{{ range .ValueString}}<strong>{{$labels.header_host}}</strong>:  {{ $value }}{{ end }}
```

This does not range at all.

Is it possible to break these alerts up/range over the value string of the grafana alert?

[ValueString appears to just be string](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/alerting/contact-points/message-templating/template-data/) but I'm not sure what I can range over. (I'm using this in the alert Description and Summary)

Here are my alert settings in Grafana

[image: Alert Settings]

To my knowledge, I can't limit the occurrences in elasticsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Classic condition` and use `Math` operation with expression `$A>500`. That will create multidimensional alert (based on `header_host` label) - each returned timeseries will be executed against this expression. See `Preview alerts`.

Comment: When using Math, I did get a unique timeseries for each label, but preview alerts showed values that were 0

Comment: @BrandonKauffman 0 means alert is not firing for that particular time serie, so that is what you want.

Comment: Thank you! I saw the alerts in the preview column and assumed they'd be shown as firing. This works.